# Creating basic apps with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

I installed PhoneGap with nodejs, and I sent the `create` command to create a folder with the basic files needed for the first app. When I open the index.html file there is a script tag that points to a file called `phonegap.js`. The problem is that this does not exist in the folder, where is it? The app is running if built without that file or not?

That is my folder:

[image]

My object is to create a basic app working.

Thanks.

Comment: You can download cordova here -  http://cordova.apache.org/, it contains all the files needed for a boilerplate app ( not created one through node ) , but that is where the cordova js ( or phonegap.js ) is .

Comment: Worth a mention, the app will work without the file, you need the file if you wish to use the camera or other native features of the device via javascript

Comment: @Rob Sedgwick Ok I had this intuition but then also to be able to use the native bees of the devices I have to add that file and I found one at this address
`C:\Users\Edoardo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin`
is the correct file?

Comment: I expect that is the file. You need to copy it to a location accessible by your web app. Say, placing it in the root next to your index.html. Like I say not created a phonegap app from node - used eclipse or Netbeans, I'm going to look into it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The file is created when you add a platform to your project (because its content is different for each platform)

For example, for an android project it should be in `platforms/android/assets/www/phone gap.js`.